# Update XML file between different application versions

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I released a windows phone application, and now I am about to release my second version, the problem is that I have an XML file that stores information, and now some elements from that XML have changed what would be the best/safest way to update between the two versions of XML, I want to migrate the settings from the XML file that is all ready installed to the new XML file without losing settings, is that possible ?

Would really appreciate your help

Regards !

Comment: How much have you changed it and what method are you using for deserialization?

Comment: I moved some settings to another XML file and added and removed some settings, xmlreader.ReadElementContentAs that is the way i am loading the settins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author a schema for each version of the XML file(s). Pick your deserialization/loading method based upon which schema validates.

In future, consider a version number as an attribute on the root element of your document.

Comment: I do have that what I wish to avoid is having to keep all the different loading methods based on the version number, what I think I'm going to do is have the removed elements still there and comment them as depreciated, and add the new elements when they are not found thanks for your comments

Comment: @OliverCiappara again, this depends on your deserialization method. If you use an `XmlSerializer`, missing elements are skipped. You can set defaults in the class' constructor.

Comment: I am using xmlReader and am adding the missing elementes on a try catch

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your application can detect whether the version of the XML file is an old version, if so map it and save a new version, then carry on as normal.

Comment: I can detect the version, but i wish for something more generic instead of having to keep every version of "read" to be able and migrate

Comment: Presumably your new version should be an extension of features from your old version. It should be simple have the new version of your XML file have the same core elements as the old version.